# Zoom functionality on a UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios, uiscrollview

I have a UITableView in one of my views which is a bit small and I can't increase its height (as its size is fixed and there are other controllers too). Can I provide the zoom in/zoom out functionality in it (same as we get on map view) ? If yes, how ?

During my search I came to know that it is possible with scroll view but I don't know how. I added a scroll view to my view and on the scroll view I added my tableview but the zoom in/zoom out functionality does not work there. Please help me out

This is for iPhone iOS 4.1.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UITableView will be consuming all the touch events in the table view. What you need to do to get around this is to intercept the touch events, identify zoom gestures, and then pass any events that aren't zoom gestures to the table view.

You can subclass UIWindow to add the touch interceptors. Look at the sendEvent method.

Comment: hey carl thanks for your inputs but suppose if i have a uibutton and i nedd zooming functionality ob that can u help me out for that without changing the frame of button (the functionality(zooming wise) just should be same as we take image view on scroll view  ) .